# A way to use "aggregator" (custom counter) within Combine step?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

My team uses a lot of aggregators (custom counters) for many of dataflow pipelines we use for monitoring and analysis purposes.

We mostly write `DoFn` classes to do so, but we sometimes use `Combine.perKey()`, by writing our own combine class that implements `SerializableFunction<Iterable<T>, S>` (usually in our case, `T` and `S` are the same). Some of the jobs we run have a small fraction of very hot keys, and we are looking to utilize some of the features offered by `Combine` (such as hot key fanout), but there is one issue with this approach.

It appears that aggregators are only available within `DoFn`, and I am wondering if there is a way around this, or this is a likely feature to be added in the future. Mostly, we use a bunch of custom counters to count the number of certain events/objects of different types for analysis and monitoring purposes. In some cases, we can probably apply another DoFn after the Combine step to do this, but in other cases we really need to count things during the combine process -- for instance, we want to know the distribution of objects over keys to understand how many hot keys we have and what draws the line between hot keys and very hot keys, for instance. There are a few other cases that seem tricky to us.

I searched around, but I couldn't find much resource around how one can use aggregators during the `Combine` step, so any help will be really appreciated!

If needed, I can perhaps describe what kind of `Combine` step we use and what we are trying to count, but it'll take some time and I'd like to have a general solution around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible. In the future (as part of Apache Beam) it is likely to be possible to define metrics (which are like aggregators) within a `CombineFn` which should address this.

In the meantime, for your use case you can do as you describe. You can have a `Combine.perKey()`, and then have multiple steps consuming the result -- one for your actual processing and others to report various metrics.

You could also look at the methods in [CombineFns](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/CombineFns) which allow creating a composed `CombineFn`. For instance, you could use your `CombineFn` and a simple `Count`, so that the reporting `DoFn` can report the number of elements in each key (consuming the `Count`) and the actual processing `DoFn` can consume the result of your `CombineFn`.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response and the suggestions. I really hope the metrics feature will be added soon!